# Rsync a video stream continously and watch it

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, webcam, rsync, fifo

I am recording a cam on a remote machine in my office. I use ffmpeg for that, and writing to mpegts file.
I want to copy that stream locally, to have a fresh copy, and watch it simultaneously.
I don't know options for rsync to grab a changing (appending) file, so I am using loop for it, and it is very slow.

```
while true; do rsync -avz --progress --partial --append remote:~/myvideo.mp4 ~/; done
```

For watching, I tried:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
tail -f ~/myvideo.mp4 > /tmp/fifo
mplayer /tmp/fifo
```

But because rsync is stopping every 5 sec, it is working unstable.

How to record and stream a remote cam continuously, and use only one network stream for that?

Comment: I see two solutions: you could just use VLC to view the resulting mp4 file (it's very capable with broken/mismatched files), or just use VLC to replace what rsync is doing by capturing the stream and saving it locally.